# Viewing Collection Called "stats" Using Mongo CLI

Tags: mongodb, command-line-interface

Not really thinking, I created a collection called `stats` to collect aggregate data in my application (using a MongoDB driver).  It appears to be saving correctly and the driver is correctly getting data from that collection without any issues.

Now the thing I didn't think about is that the `db` has a method called `stats` that gives you statistics on how the db instance is doing.  This effectively makes it impossible to view records in the `stats` collection via the CLI.

Edited output of `show collections`:

```
<SNIP>:PRIMARY> show collections
alerts
categories
companies
customers
states
stats
system.indexes
system.profile
system.users
users
```

Output when attempting a `.findOne()`:

```
<SNIP>:PRIMARY> db.stats.findOne({})
2015-09-24T14:28:25.797-0500 E QUERY    TypeError: Object function (scale){
    return this.runCommand( { dbstats : 1 , scale : scale } );
} has no method 'findOne'
    at (shell):1:10
```

Is there a way of interacting with the `stats` collection via CLI at this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the db.getCollection() method - explictly created for this type of situation :)

```
db.getCollection("stats").findOne()
```

Comment: Haha, that did it!  Thanks. :D